# What is the correct type hint to use when exporting a pydantic model as a dict?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, pydantic

I'm writing an abstraction module which validates an excel sheet against a pydantic schema and returns the row as a dict using `dict(MyCustomModel(**sheet_row))`
. I would like to use type hinting so any function that uses the abstraction methods gets a type hint for the returned dictionary with its keys instead of just getting an unhelpful dict. Basically I'd like to return the keys of the dict that compose the schema so I don't have to keep referring to the schema for its fields and to catch any errors early on.

My current workaround is having my abstraction library return the pydantic model directly and type hint using the Model itself. This means every field has to be accessed using a dot notation instead of accessing it like a regular dictionary. I cannot annotate the dict has being the model itself as its a dict, not the actual pydantic model which has some extra attributes as well.

I tried type hinting with the type `MyCustomModel.__dict__()`. That resulted in the error `TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got mappingproxy({'__config__': <class 'foo.bar.Config'>, '__fields__': {'lab.`. Is there a way to send a type hint about the fields in the schema, but as a dictionary? I don't omit any keys during the dict export. All the fields in the model is present in the final dict being returned

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. I believe the type hint for a dict created from a pydantic model would be `dict[str, Any]`.

Comment: Please take the time to provide some actual code, when you ask such questions. In this case, the relevant function signatures would be sufficient, no need for the function bodies because you are asking about annotations. Concise, minimal, reproducible code typically conveys the problem much faster and better than paragraphs of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to try and abstract that question and create minimal reproducible example for you.

### Question

Consider this working example:

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: str
    y: int


def validate(data: dict[str, Any], model: type[BaseModel]) -> dict[str, Any]:
    return dict(model.parse_obj(data))


def test() -> None:
    data = {"x": "spam", "y": "123"}
    validated = validate(data, Foo)
    print(validated)
    # reveal_type(validated["x"])
    # reveal_type(validated["y"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

The code works fine and outputs `{'x': 'spam', 'y': 123}` as expected. But if you uncomment the `reveal_type` lines and run `mypy` over it, obviously the type it sees is just `Any` for both.

Is there a way to annotate `validate`, so that a type checker knows, which keys will be present in the returned dictionary, based on the model provided to it?

### Answer

Python dictionaries have no mechanism built into them for distinguishing their type via specific keys. The generic `dict` type is parameterized by exactly two type parameters, namely the key type and the value type.

You can utilize the [`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) class to define a type based on the specific keys of a dictionary. However (as pointed out by @hernán-alarcón in the comments) the `__dict__` method still returns just a `dict[str, Any]`. You can always [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) the output of course and for this particular `Foo` model this would work:

```py
from typing import Any, TypedDict, cast

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: str
    y: int


class FooDict(TypedDict):
    x: str
    y: int


def validate(data: dict[str, Any], model: type[BaseModel]) -> FooDict:
    return cast(FooDict, dict(model.parse_obj(data)))


def test() -> None:
    data = {"x": "spam", "y": "123"}
    validated = validate(data, Foo)
    print(validated)
    reveal_type(validated["x"])  # "builtins.str"
    reveal_type(validated["y"])  # "builtins.int"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

But it is not very helpful, if `validate` should be able to deal with any model, not just `Foo`.

The easiest way to generalize this that I can think of is to make your own base model class that is **generic** in terms of the corresponding `TypedDict`. Binding the type argument in a dedicated private attribute should be enough. You won't actually have to set it or interact with it at any point. It is enough to specify it, when you subclass your base class. Here is a working example:

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar, TypedDict, cast

from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBaseModel, PrivateAttr

T = TypeVar("T")

class BaseModel(PydanticBaseModel, Generic[T]):
    __typed_dict__: type[T] = PrivateAttr(...)

class FooDict(TypedDict):
    x: str
    y: int

class Foo(BaseModel[FooDict]):
    x: str
    y: int

def validate(data: dict[str, Any], model: type[BaseModel[T]]) -> T:
    return cast(T, model.parse_obj(data).dict())

def test() -> None:
    data = {"x": "spam", "y": "123"}
    validated = validate(data, Foo)
    print(validated)
    reveal_type(validated["x"])  # "builtins.str"
    reveal_type(validated["y"])  # "builtins.int"
    reveal_type(validated)       # "TypedDict('FooDict', {'x': builtins.str, 'y': builtins.int})"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

This works well enough to convey the dictionary keys and corresponding types.

If you are wondering, whether there is a way to just **dynamically** infer the `TypedDict` rather than just duplicating the model fields manually, the answer is no.

> Static type checkers do not execute your code, they just read it.

This brings me to the final consideration. I don't know, why you would even want to use a dictionary over a model instance in the first place. It seems that for the purposes of dealing with structured data, the model is superior in every aspect, if you already are using Pydantic anyway.

The fact that you access the fields as attributes (via dot-notation) is a feature IMHO and not a drawback of this approach. If you for some reason do need to have dynamic attribute access via field names as strings, you can always just use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) on the model instance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I asuumed pydantic was supposed to be used ‘internally’ and once it has been validated, only dicts should be used after that.  I see that is not the case and I’ll start using the model directly

Comment: Very nicely explained, thank you. I was just thinking about ways to handle this dilemma (new to Pydantic, started with the TOML config and extended to others mpdules, I used to use ["attr"]systax, many times with variables and yesterday also started to use __getattr__ and __setattr__. I had the impression that I'm thinking this all wrong, so this is how it is.

I have strict typing tendencies (C/C++ origin) and Python is not the best language for this.